# How to split Eloquent Relationship result by attribute and take only count

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three tables:

```
Table : projects
id, name

Table : services
id, project_id, name

Table : tasks
id, service_id, name, completed
```

- Every project has many services
- Every service has many tasks

My Eloquent Models have the following relationships, as said before:

```
class Project {
   public function services() {
      $this->hasMany('App\Service', 'project_id');
   }

class Service {
   public function project() {
      $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'project_id');
   }

   public function tasks() {
      $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'service_id');
   }

class Task() {
   public function service() {
      $this->belongsTo('App\Service', 'service_id');
   }
}
```

The Service has many Tasks. If all the tasks of the service have 'complete' = true , then the Service is completed

Now I want to query LAST 5 PROJECTS, with the COMPLETED SERVICES COUNT and the NOT COMPLETED SERVICES COUNT.

For example:

- Service 1 and Service 2 belong to project 1
- Task 1 (completed) and Task 2 (completed) belong to Service 1
- Task 3 (completed) and Task 4 (not completed) belong to Service 2

In this case, project 1 has 2 services: service 1 (completed, because all its tasks are completed) and service 2 (not completed, because one task is still not completed).

So the result would be : project1 (all its data) with count(services_completed) (will be 1) and with count(services_uncompleted) (will be 1, too).

I want to query the last x projects. How can i do to query all this data one time, avoiding the queries during a foreach cycle to scan the projects array?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel - would SQL suffice for an answer?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can actually produce the query in SQL. I'm interested in a solution with Eloquent Models and its relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a "completed" flag on the services table. I know that seems redundant and you have to keep the flag updated but every query on the Services should be easier.

Comment: thank you. This is my solution, too. I added the "completed" column to Services and I keep it updated with a TaskObserver.

Comment: The completed flag on services is also good from a logical point of view, you can have a Service completed even if not all the tasks were completed (i.e. a task was cancelled).